# Flask host='0.0.0.0' Google Chrome could not connect

Tags: flask

I just begun using Flask and tried to run the hello_world example (hello.py)

The point is that I run the server through ssh on a remote machine and I want to browse it from my local machine so I used

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0'),
```

However when I browse on chrome I put let's say http: //RemoteMachineIP:5000/ I got:

Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to RemoteMachineIP:5000

The remote machine has multiple ethernet IP addresses so I tried them (as http: //RemoteMachineIP:5000/) and I am always getting the same error.

I have also tried using `app.run(host='LocalMachineIP')` in `hello.py` but I got this error `Flask [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address.`

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Why the `@`? Can you try without it?

Comment: It is without the @ I just wrote it to mean trhe IP address of the remote Machine.

Comment: Probably that port is in use. Can you try running on a different port with `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)` ?

Comment: I tried it however whatever IP adress I try on my Local machine browser (http://a.b.c.d:8000/), I got: Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to a.b.c.d:8000

Comment: Maybe you have a firewall that prevents outsiders to connect?

Comment: Is the remote machine on the same LAN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can run the server but the browser won't see it, it is a firewall problem.

If you can't assign the ip port, probably there is a PID already using the port, so you should try

```
lsof -i :5000
```

Then

```
kill -9 [PID From the lsof]
```